# router.navigate() not working and not throwing error

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, angular2-routing

I have this method :

```
  private redirect(path: string): void {
    this.router.navigate([path]);
  }
```

That is called in this one :

```
  private onError(error: any): void {
    switch (error.status) {
      case 401: // Unauthorized.
        this.redirect('auth/login');
      break;
    }
```

That is called from this (this is the get from httpService)

```
public get(url: string, requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    this.requestInterceptor();
    return super.get(this.getFullUrl(url), this.requestOptions(requestOptions))
      .do((res: Response) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          this.onSuccess(res);
        }
      }, (error: any) => {
        this.onError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.onFinally();
      });
  }
```

=> Navigate does not work, nothing happens, no error throwing no log. I tried to log before and after the call. I get the log before but not after... So there is a problem.

I use the same navigate in other places with no issue but here I don't see why it would not work .

Any Idea ?

EDIT :

This is a service :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    public router: Router,
    public alertService: AlertService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }
  // Here the get() method
}
```

In the parent core.module there is a factory :

```
export function HttpFactory(backend: XHRBackend,
                            defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                            router: Router,
                            alertService: AlertService): HttpService {
  return new HttpService(backend, defaultOptions, router, alertService);
}
```

Comment: Your redirect method is never used

Comment: Not that obvious, I edited the question. I logged inside the `case 401` but it never go after the this.redirect(). it just stop there without any log or anything

Comment: Post of the code of the entire class / component you have and how do you inject `router`.

Comment: That was a good advice I resolved the issue thanks to that thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I forgot to add the proper dependencies during declaration  :

```
service,
{
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: HttpFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router],
}
```

`Router` was missing